# Ajax receber lista de String de um WebMethod

Tags: c#, ajax

Preciso passar uma lista de string de um método do server para o ajax, porém não funciona.
Se passo apenas uma string dá certo.

Segue o código:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public List<string> MontarGrafico()
    {
          var l = new List<string>();
          l.Add("teste1");
          l.Add("teste2");
          return l;
    }
```

E no ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Grafico.aspx/MontarGrafico",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (produtos) {
            var prods = produtos.d;
            $.each(prods, function (index, prod) {
                alert(prod);
            });                
        }
    });
```

Porém ele não exibe nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve ta dando esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, falha ao autenticar, para contornar tal problema vai na pasta `App_Start`, abra o arquivo `RouteConfig.cs` e deixou assim, sendo que na segunda linha coloque como `RedirectMode.Off`

```cs
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
       settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
       routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
    }
}
```

Pronto vai funcionar de imediato.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***Um dica:*** faça um `WebService.asmx`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
namespace WebApplication2
{   

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebServiceDados : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod()]
        public List<string> MontarGrafico()
        {
            var l = new List<string>();
            l.Add("teste1");
            l.Add("teste2");
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript Ajax:

```cs
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebServiceDados.asmx/MontarGrafico",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (produtos) {
            var prods = produtos.d;
            $.each(prods, function (index, prod) {
                alert(prod);
            });                
        }
});
```

Nesse modo não precisa mexer naquela configuração `RouteConfig.cs`

Outro ponto a observar é do envio e recebimento, configure seu `jsonSerialization` no seu WebConfig, para receber/enviar dados com tamanhos grandes

```cs
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Obs: para verificar os erros eu instalo o [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite), um plugin muito utilizado que pega erros `Javascript` pelo navegador.

Comment: Adicionei o WebService.asmx, e deu certo. Como faço para visualizar aquela parte do Post? O print que você colocou?

Comment: Eu utilizo um plugin no google chrome Firebug Lite: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite